# File "Expires" after 2-3 minutes swift

Tags: swift, xcode, document

Here is the problem: I open document with

```
func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAt url: URL){}
```

save url like this:
"/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E8D502A1-7F9E-4E62-8DE3-7B66D711E35D/tmp/appName/15072021.ppdf»

and after some time i want to share this file with

`UIDocumentInteractionController(url: url)`

but

```
FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: url.path)
```

returns false, so i cannot do that

can anybody help?

Comment: Ask not what `UIDocumentPickerViewController` can do for you.  Ask what you can do for security-scoped bookmarks.

Comment: thats a great hint actually, reading article on it. Thanks!!

Comment: well, I think it's more about macOS rather than  ios (

Answer (score 0):

When importing a document using Document Picker, a copy of selected document is saved in a temporary location. If you plan to use this document later on, you must move it to a proper space in your app sandbox.
Here is what [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerdelegate/1618680-documentpicker) says:

> The meaning of the provided URL varies depending on the document picker’s mode:
>
> - UIDocumentPickerModeImport
>
>   The URL refers to a copy of the selected document. This document is a temporary file. It remains available only until your application terminates. To keep a permanent copy, you must move this file to a permanent location inside your sandbox.